# SQL: How can I get a UniqueIdentifier Column in this query

Tags: mysql, sql

Some background explanations:
I have some tables and want to get the lowest date of each Position.
A Position has multiple departments in which the dates are stored.

Sample:
Position 1 has
Department date 1: 30.05.2019,
Department date 2: 01.06.2019,
Department date 3: 05.06.2019.... and so on

**I have a problem to get the UniqueIdentifier Column id_abteilungen in the following output:**

[Result of Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ffKB6.jpg)

The used Query to get the above result is this:

SQL

```
SELECT tbl_Auftrag.Auftragsnummer
     , tbl_Positionen.Bezeichnung
     , MIN(tbl_Positionen_Abteilungen.Abteilungstermin) AS Abteilungstermin
FROM tbl_Auftrag 
INNER JOIN tbl_Positionen 
ON tbl_Auftrag.auftrag_id = tbl_Positionen.id_auftrag 
INNER JOIN tbl_Positionen_Abteilungen 
ON tbl_Positionen.positionen_id = tbl_Positionen_Abteilungen.id_positionen
WHERE tbl_Positionen_Abteilungen.fertiggestellt = '0'
GROUP BY tbl_Positionen_Abteilungen.id_positionen
       , tbl_Auftrag.Auftragsnummer
       , tbl_Positionen.Bezeichnung
```

To get this result I needed to GROUP BY id_positionen.
As soon as I try to GROUP BY id_positionen, id_abteilungen
the result will show all Positions with all departments and their dates again.

[Output with GROUP BY id_positionen, id_abteilungen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohT4m.jpg)

The achieved result has to be like this but I simply dont know how to get this result:

[Output I wish like to have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KoihB.jpg)

If there are questions regarding the Tables and the primary and foreign keys, or may something different you need to know - feel free to ask. All I need is the correct query to get the id_abteilungen Unique Identifier, beside the other columns shown in Result of Query image, of each lowest date found in a position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't  shoudl use  tbl_Positionen_Abteilungen.id_positionen in group  by
instead you should select your ersult joining a subqiery for min Abteilungstermin

```
    select  * 
    FROM tbl_Auftrag 
    INNER JOIN tbl_Positionen ON tbl_Auftrag.auftrag_id = tbl_Positionen.id_auftrag 
    INNER JOIN tbl_Positionen_Abteilungen ON tbl_Positionen.positionen_id = tbl_Positionen_Abteilungen.id_positionen
    INNER JOIN  (
        SELECT tbl_Auftrag.Auftragsnummer
            , tbl_Positionen.Bezeichnung
            , MIN(tbl_Positionen_Abteilungen.Abteilungstermin) AS Abteilungstermin
        FROM tbl_Auftrag 
        INNER JOIN tbl_Positionen ON tbl_Auftrag.auftrag_id = tbl_Positionen.id_auftrag 
        INNER JOIN tbl_Positionen_Abteilungen ON tbl_Positionen.positionen_id = tbl_Positionen_Abteilungen.id_positionen
        WHERE tbl_Positionen_Abteilungen.fertiggestellt = '0'
        GROUP BY  tbl_Auftrag.Auftragsnummer, tbl_Positionen.Bezeichnung
    ) t on t.Auftragsnummer = tbl_Auftrag.Auftragsnummer 
        and t.Bezeichnung =  tbl_Positionen.Bezeichnung 
        and t.Abteilungstermin = tbl_Positionen_Abteilungen.Abteilungstermin
    WHERE tbl_Positionen_Abteilungen.fertiggestellt = '0'
```